# Solutions manual for Analysis On Manifolds Chapter 3 (section 13)

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request

Solutions manual for Analysis On Manifolds Chapter 3 (section 13)

Actually, I just want to verify my solutions but it is not possible to upload every solution herefor a check. So If there is any solution manual for the chapter 3 of Analysis of Manifolds by J. Munkres, then that would be highly helpful.